# Typing on a Browser console

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, browser, console, edit

This might sound trivial but I need to to add some lines to the Chrome's Javascript browser console on Ubuntu. I've opened the browser console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and when I try to type in, nothing happens(the console's not editable). Are there any steps that am missing here?

**Browser Console**

[image: Browser Console]

[image: warning]

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+K for web console

Comment: Thanks. This works

Comment: Can you mark my post as answered :)

Comment: Sure, I was to, and I can do it only after 5 minutes since the time an answer is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ctrl+Shift+K for web console to execute Javascript expressions